# Swipe to delete for a custom view not for list item

Tags: android, android-animation

I want to develop a layout with a very simple ImageView and a Listview binded in a Relativelayout . Now for a better user experience I want to delete the Image view by swiping it left or right same like what is implemented in android Gmail app to delete emails.

Implementing it on a listview item is very simple and there are many tuts and sample codes are available over the internet including the official Google I/O talk on animation and explained in a very good way by Chet Hasse here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YCHNAi9kJI4

but I don't require to implement it on the listview items insted I want to implement it in more generic way. In my case I want the same behaviour for my ImageView item as one view and ListView another . Like shown below

[image: layout]

As soon as the ImageView item is deleted the whole ListView should smoothly come on the top.

I have tried many way to implement the same without any success.

Suggest me the approach or some samples to do this which is supported in Gingerbread and above android OS.

Comment: https://github.com/romannurik/Android-SwipeToDismiss/blob/master/src/com/example/android/swipedismiss/SwipeDismissTouchListener.java

Comment: Thanks @GabrieleMariotti but this only supports after API level 14, I need the same behaviour for API level 9 and higher.

Comment: Just use NineOldAndroids to support old versions of Android as described in readme. https://github.com/JakeWharton/SwipeToDismissNOA

Comment: awesome @GabrieleMariotti thanks a ton and also a big Thanks to Jack for his great library. Gabriele please include all this in to an answer, you deserve a green tick.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this code:

https://github.com/romannurik/Android-SwipeToDismiss/blob/master/src/com/example/android/swipedismiss/SwipeDismissTouchListener.java

As described in [readme](https://github.com/romannurik/Android-SwipeToDismiss) this code works for android 14+.

You can use the NineOldAndroids [library](http://nineoldandroids.com/) to support old versions of Android, or use the Jake Wharton's port:

https://github.com/JakeWharton/SwipeToDismissNOA

Answer (score 1):

I looked around and found this helpful.
https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a custom ViewGroup that takes one child and allows you to drag/fling it to the left with a callback once the swipe is complete. My intention was for it to work just like in a RecyclerView. Works well in a LinearLayout with animateLayoutChanges=true and setting the visibility to GONE in the callback.

Gist here: https://gist.github.com/darnmason/38a1a5178a06470202784050f4dc1cdf

Answer (score -2):

All you need is this library:  https://github.com/timroes/EnhancedListView

Comment: as mentioned I don't want it for items in a listview but generic one for any two different Views like ImageView and ListView in my case.